# R markdown knitting error no tidyselect variables selected

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, tidyverse, tidyr

I am trying to knit my code to an html file; however, when the file reaches the line of code that contains the function `pivot_longer()`, an error appears ([see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xopW0.jpg)). I will attach my code below. Any suggestions? 
[dataset (.csv file)](https://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/data/co2-2019.csv)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dslabs)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
dt <- read.csv("~co2-2019.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dt[,i] <- apply(dt[,i], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
dt.long <- pivot_longer(dt, -year, names_to = "month", values_to = "co2")
dt.long <- mutate(dt.long, month = factor(month, levels = month.abb))
dt.long <- group_by(dt.long, year, month) %>% summarize(mean_co2 = mean(co2, na.rm = TRUE))
ggplot(dt.long, aes(x=month, y=mean_co2, group = year))+ggtitle("Average Annual CO2 Levels at Mauna Loa Observatory")+geom_line()+labs(x="Month", y = "Average CO2 Level")
```

Comment: That's the error you would get if `dt` didn't contain a column named `year`. I didn't download your data, but if you post the first few lines in the question (`dput` is the best way to do this, `dput(droplevels(dt[1:10, ]))`, I'd be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what you are trying to execute with line:

`dt[,i] <- apply(dt[,i], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

But I guess, you are trying to convert the Jan and Feb columns to numeric which will be read as char by the first command and if its like that then use:

`dt[,2:3] <- apply(dt[,2:3], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

to explicitly convert only those two columns. Try knitting the code after the changes and it should generate html successfully.

I would recommend to use `str(dt)` to check which columns has been read as what type.